# iCarousel - Change center item Dynamically iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, icarousel

I am using iCarousel in my iPad application, i would like to know if there is way to change the view of the center item dynamically whenever selected. In short i would like to achieve something like this[image] 
I managed to set the first index (item - 0) to red, but i could not figure out a way to do the following:

When 1 is selected i wish to change the image of 0 to plain white and 1 to red.

Something for 2 as well.

Any Help or Advise would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to select item and then change the colour then just simply use:

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
//change the view of current index
}
```

If you want current item colour is red without select, then you need to do more things:

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view{
//Here you need to check current index
    if (index == self.carousel.currentItemIndex) {
    //change the view
    }
}
```

And also you need to use this method to check index changed or not:

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel{
//you need to reload carousel for update view of current index
[self.carousel reloadData];
}
```

Comment: If I want to Change the colour in didSelectItemAtIndex , then what I need to do exactly ? How I will get selected view reference ?

Comment: @AvijitDas You may have a array of custom views as a data source of iCarousel. And simply get reference from customView[index]?Is that you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks yah I am looking for accessing property of the view which is currently selected. I have used currentItemView method under  didSelectItemAtIndex function and I achieved my goal . Here is the code          ReflectionView *refelctionView = (ReflectionView*)self.carousel.currentItemView;

Comment: Helpful answer, but when you click item in carousel, its lagging little bit, because of reloading carousel.

Answer (score 0):

iCarousel has a delegate method

```
- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

which gets called whenever you select an item and **index** gives you the index of currently selected item. You can change the color of the view using this index. Also you can save the index of your previous view in any integer variable and use the same to reset that tile's color.